# Math.Round decimal in Visual Studio C# not rounding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rounding

I would like my calc to return a decimal that is two places.
I Googled and found Math.Round function.
I applied it to my code in several places i.e. after the variables are declared, before the return statement, before the calculation line, and after the calculation line, but get $251.333333333333 as my result.
My code looks like this:

```
public decimal finalCalc()
    {
        decimal calcNumber3;
        decimal g = firstPartofCalc();
        decimal h = secondPartofCalc();

        if (rbMonthlyPay.Checked)
        {
            Math.Round(calcNumber3 = (((g + h) * 52) / 12), 2) ;
        }
        else
        {
            calcNumber3 = g + h;
        }
        return calcNumber3;
    }
```

Calcs 1 and 2 return decimal results. I know that there are a few other ways of getting the same result including returning the result as a string. But, as a newbie to the coding thing, I would really love to understand why this is not working.

TIA
Vickie

Comment: `Math.Round(calcNumber3 =` ??

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C#?

Comment: What ever is happening, you are performing *[integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-)* which is likely going to give you strange results, try `(((g + h) * 52) / (decimal)12)` or  `(((g + h) * 52) / 12m)`

Comment: Furthermore : *integer division* will return the *quotient* of the two operands  `x / y` rounded towards zero, the quotient can be thought of as integer part of a division... And this is why we cant have nice things...

Comment: It's important to note  `Math.Round(anyVariable = ...)` is _vastly_ different than `anyVariable = Math.Round(...)`.  You are not using the return value.

Comment: `calcNumber3 = (g + h) * 52 / 12; calcNumber3 = Math.Round(calcNumber3, 2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning calculated value to calcNumber3 properly, Change it to:

```
calcNumber3 = Math.Round((((g + h) * 52) / 12), 2) ;
```